# Reading JIRA Issues through .NET

Tags: .net, json, rest, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm using JIRA 6.1.3 and am trying to interface with a .Net program. The main option I see is the REST API (since SOAP is deprecated).

I've found a .Net REST client here: https://bitbucket.org/dpbevin/jira-rest-client-dot-net/overview but it doesn't seem to support getting custom fields.

It seems my other option is to use an HTTP Request to get the JSON for the issue from the server through the REST API. This seems like it must have been done before, and I'm curious if anyone has some suggestions before I start parsing JSON.

How can I get the customfields with either a client or by parsing?

Answer (score 0):

Try using "customfield_XXXX" as ID when you try to access custom field.
XXXX is ID for the custom field that you may get from Custom fields page. 
Hover over configure option against the field of your interest.
URL should end with something like - customFieldId=11500

Comment: This is not supported by the REST client I listed and otherwise would be covered by me parsing the JSON myself. Thanks though.

Comment: can i fetch a particular customfield_xxxx for all issues at one time through rest api ?